# Is the study on the theory of the integral of Denjoy's and Perron's an active field nowadays?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, soft-question

I am an undergraduate student knowing the basic definition on the integral of Denjoy's and Perron's. I wonder if this topic is still active nowadays.

- Is the integral of Denjoy's and Perron's worth devoting time to study for a student planning to read a master/ PhD degree in analysis?
- Is the study on the theory of the integral of Denjoy's and Perron's an active field nowadays? What problem interests researchers on these two integrals most? Is there some "big" open problems students with the knowledge of measure theory and functional analysis can understand?
- What branch of analysis uses the integral of Denjoy's and Perron's frequently?

Comment: take a look at zbMath's (only) subject entry on the issue: https://zbmath.org/classification/?q=denjoy+%7C+perron

Comment: @ac15 Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the [Henstock–Kurzweil integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henstock%E2%80%93Kurzweil_integral) approach is more generally popular now. As for actual research in these integrals (as opposed to simply some basic knowledge about them), it certainly exists today, but it's restricted to a relatively small number of researchers, which incidentally is mostly true for probably the vast majority of mathematics research -- unlike the sense one might get from blogs, semi-popular accounts, and the like, where it may seem that everyone works on things like higher category theory, stuff arising from Perlman's and Wiles' work, NP-completeness, the Axiom of Choice, string theory, etc. Regarding your first question, a basic awareness of what these integrals are would most likely be worth having, but probably not a detailed study of them unless you're in an area of analysis where these integrals play an important role in that area. For surveys of work in this area, see:

Ralph Henstock, [*A short history of integration theory*](http://www.seams-bull-math.ynu.edu.cn/archive.jsp), **Southeast Asian Bulletin of Mathematics** 12 #2 (1988), pp. 75-95. (has 262 references)

> To access a .pdf file, select "Archive" (left side of page), then in the drop-down menu (middle, near the top) select '1988' for "Year" and '02' for "Issue".

Peter Bullen, [*Non-absolute integrals in the twentieth century*](https://www.emis.de/proceedings/Toronto2000/papers/bullen.pdf), AMS Special Session on Nonabsolute Integration, 23-24 September 2000, 27 pages. (has 195 references)

Note that the literature includes quite a few "named integrals" that are almost never mentioned online (outside of archived research papers and preprints), such as the integrals of Bochner, Burkill, Jeffery, Khintchine, Kolmogorov, Kubota, Ridder, Saks, and Ward.

The answers to the mathoverflow question [Reference for the fact that the images of the narrow and wide Denjoy integrals are respectively $ACG_\ast$ and $ACG$?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/157626/15780) may also be useful, at least for some pointers to the original literature and subsequent expository accounts of the Denjoy integral.